# Not valid use keyword as an identifier --> ReadOnly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a custom component and I need to create a property called "ReadOnly", and I get error message: "Not valid use keyword as an identifier"

Code is as follows:

```
'ReadOnly
Public Property ReadOnly As Boolean
    Get
        Return Me.Properties.ReadOnly
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        Me.Properties.ReadOnly = value
    End Set
End Property
```

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Well.. I have to wrap ReadOnly with brackets `[ReadOnly]`

Comment: yes, I misread what you were up to.  whats this Me.Properties part though?  what is properties and why go there rather than a backing field?

Comment: ReadOnly is a reserved word.  You canot use it for a property name just like you couldn't use "Property" or "Public" as a property name.

Comment: I am creating a control which inherits of a other control (of a 3rd-party) and I need to create standard properties to compatibility, that is the reason for Me.Properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is pretty obvious...You are using a reserved keyword as a name of a property, and you can't do that. It's almost like writing this code: `Dim Integer As Integer`. It can't be done.

You might wanna take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx). As it says :

> The following keywords are reserved, which means you cannot use them as names for your programming elements such as variables or procedures. You can bypass this restriction by enclosing the name in brackets ([ ]).